# Does Apache Velocity support searching for templates recursively?

Tags: java, apache, velocity

Velocity config

```
resource.loader = file
file.resource.loader.class = 
org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader
file.resource.loader.path = /path/to/templates
```

Folder Structure

- templates/

  - top-level-template.vm
  - email-templates/

    - email-1.vm
    - email-2.vm
  - webpage-templates/

    - page-1.vm
    - page-1.vm

Code snippet

```
Velocity.mergeTemplate(templateName, "UTF-8", context, writer);
```

If **templateName** is *top-level-template.vm* then Velocity finds the template however if it is *email-1.vm* or any other template in a sub-directory then Velocity throws a **ResourceNotFoundException**.

I would like to be able to specify the path to the root directory where my templates are stored and have Velocity find all templates under sub-directories.

Is there some configuration or [ResourceLoader](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/runtime/resource/loader/ResourceLoader.html) that supports finding templates recursively?

Answer (score 0):

If your structure is using sub directories, just use it in path

```
 email-templates/email-1.vm
```

In case you have same file name in different sub folders,as `header.vm`, your suggested approach will failed

Comment: Yes it would fail if two templates share the same name. I am thinking about implementing a custom ResourceLoader which would require all template names to be unique.